# regular expressions to determine if a string starts with ;

Tags: java, regex

The requirement is simple: if the given string matches:

1. starts with ';'
2. starts with some char or chars among '\r','\n','\t',' ', and then followed with ';'.
   For example ";", "\r;","\r\n;", "     \r\n   \t;" should all be ok.

Here is my code and it does not work:

```
    private static String regex = "[\\r|\\n| |\\t]+;";
    private static boolean startsWithSemicolon(String str) {
        return str.matches(regex);
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use: `"[\\r\\n\\t ]*;.*"` as regex.

Comment: `return str.trim().startsWith(";");`

Comment: https://regexr.com/5vslg

Comment: @DevilsHnd Yes this does work! I thought of this resolution but did not go that way, worrying about there might be chars that cannot be trimmed in the future.

Comment: @decpk Interesting website. I will bookmark it. After adding the " " in the regex, it works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 choices:

- Use `matches()`, in which case the regex must match the *entire* input, so you'd have to add matching of characters following the `;`.

  Regex: `str.matches("[\\r\\n\\t ]*;.*")`
  or: `Pattern.compile("[\\r\\n\\t ]*;.*").matcher(str).matches()`
- Use `find()`, in which case the regex must be anchored to the beginning of the input:

  Regex: `Pattern.compile("^[\\r\\n\\t ]*;").matcher(str).find()`

Comment: private static String regex = "[\\r\\n\\t ]*;.*";
    private static boolean startsWithSemicolon(String str) {
        str = "\r\n \t" + str;
        return str.matches(regex);
    }
I changed my code but it still does not work. Does the order of chars in [] matter? In my case some of them may be in random orders, or does not exist.

Comment: Oh, the Pattern.compile...works! That's great, thank a lot.